# SSH and VNC functionality stops working after a week or so

Tags: raspbian, networking, ssh, vnc

I'm running a raspberry pi 4 model B as a private server using raspbian. When I set it up and enable ssh and vnc functionality I can access it via both of those methods from other computers just fine. After a week or so they stop working all of the sudden despite the fact that my internet is working just fine and the fact the my pi can access the internet just fine (as evidenced by the pi showing up as online when I start syncthing on one of my PCs).

I've tried to power cycle the pi, reset my router/modem, unplug the pi from the ethernet which causes it to switch to wifi, none of which help with the issue. Deleting my known_hosts file for ssh on my PC and then trying to reconnect doesn't help either.

I haven't messed around with the firewall and network settings at all with the exception of connecting it to my wifi network in case I cannot connect it via ethernet. My packages are always kept up to date and the ip address hasn't been changed at all.

When I attempt to vnc into the pi I simply get a generic "connection lost" message and when I try to ssh into the pi I get a "no route to host" message. Pinging the pi results in 100 percent packet loss.

Only thing that fixes this issue temporarily is wiping the sd card and reinstalling raspbian, after which the problem comes back a week or so later. I've also double checked my router settings to make sure it's allowing computers on the network to communicate with each other.

Comment: It sounds like your Pi is no longer connected to the network..   That could be for lots of reasons.   I suggest that you look at the logs of the Pi and see if there are indications of what could be the cause.   /var/log/syslog is a good place to start.

Comment: I had a similar issue with a headless  RPI0W which would be fine for a couple of days then disappear unless I power cycled it.    I configured the micro USB as a USB gadget ethernet device so I could use it to login via another pi via a long isn cable and discovered it was the wifi dropping out.

I've configured the Pi to recover now..